# PHP PDO Connect to Advantage Database SQL Server

Tags: php, pdo, advantage-database-server

Our EMR software uses Advantage Database SQL server as its database and I'm creating various PHP projects which require interaction with this database.

What is the best approach to connecting and working with Advantage DB SQL and PHP? I'd like to connect on a read-only level to prevent any data wrong-doing with insurance/patient/provider records.

Note: I connect to other databases using PDO drivers. Is there an Advantage DB driver for PDO that I'm unaware of?

Server info:
PHP, Windows 2008, IIS 7

Answer (score 3):

PHP PDO support is slated for release in v11.0 of Advantage later this summer.  It is listed on our user voice feature request site here: [PDO feature request](http://feedback.advantagedatabase.com/forums/2671-general/suggestions/539345-add-pdo-support-php-data-objects-?ref=title).

You can view our PHP documentation online on our developer zone website here: [PHP Documentation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?php_product_overview.htm).

Comment: Thanks Peter! Sure wish it was handy now :)

Comment: +1, it's always great to see vendors here providing canonical answers.

Answer (score 2):

On the [features page](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver) for the product, they list an [ODBC connector](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver/odbc-driver) under the "Servers & Clients" section.

It happens that PDO [can speak ODBC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).  This is probably your best bet.

They also have a [separate PHP extension](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver/php-extension), however they're hiding it being a registration wall and the documentation does not seem to be public.  Whether it includes a PDO driver is not stated.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Seems like I will need to update to PHP 5.3 in order to make the PHP extension work.

Comment: Moving to 5.3 is quite worth it.

Comment: You can also download the driver from the Advantage Developer Zone.  The helpfile and knowledge base are there as well.  http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com