# What is the proper connection string for Advantage Database Server?

Tags: php, sql, advantage-database-server

I am running [Sybase Advantage Database Server](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/) and a bit new to PHP coding.  Advantage Database's knowledge base with code samples went offline awhile back, so I don't have much to go off of.

What would be the proper database connection string to use with Sybase's Advantage Database 10 in php?

This string works perfect in classic ASP:

```
<%
Set AdvConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
AdvConn.Open "DSN=AdvantageWintux"

Set Colors = AdvConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Colors ORDER BY Color")

If Not Colors.EOF Then
    While Not Colors.EOF
    Response.Write(Colors("Color") & "<BR>")
Colors.MoveNext
Wend
Colors.Close
End If
%>
```

What would the PHP version of the connection string be?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532699/how-can-i-connect-to-local-advantage-database-using-pyodbc-in-python

Comment: and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525136/advantage-php-pdo-driver-on-php7

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918003/connecting-to-an-advantage-database-with-php-on-windows

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994158/php-pdo-connect-to-advantage-database-sql-server

Comment: While there is nothing specific for PHP there, you can get examples of some connection strings for ADS from https://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-advantage/ The Advantage help file (installed with the PHP driver and Advantage Data Architect) also has information on connection string parameters (search for *Connection string* in the index).