# How to create a database for Advantage Database Server(ADS)?

Tags: ads, advantage-database-server

I have installed the ADS 10.0 version on my win7 successful, and it run as a windows service. Then I take a look at windows program menu and found there is a menu named "Advantage Database Server" and it only includes "Advantage Configuration Utility" sub-menu, I open it and have no found where can create database.

My question:

1. How to connect my server above? Does need another tool?
2. If I can connet the server, how to create database? Advantage Database Architect?
3. If I created a database, how to connect to that with IP/Port in ODBC for a client?(I know how to connect a ADS database with the path in ODBC)

Any one can help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The Advantage Configuration Utility tells you whether the service is running and you can start and stop it from there (or from the Windows Service Manager).

Since ADS is a hybrid between a client/server and a desktop database the meaning of `database` is depending on the context, it can be:

1. A directory that has some tables (`.adt` or `.dbf` files with optional additional files for index, lob data, etc.) in it.
2. An Advantage Database Dictionary (a filename that ends with `.add` that links to addtional files and eventually table files as in 1.).
3. A server side alias (`\\MYADSSERVER\MYALIAS`).
4. The server itself that has an ADS service running on some socket (`ip:port`).
5. An Advantage Internet Server (`AIS`).

The simplest case would be 1. Where you just put some existing tables in a directory (or create new tables with Advantage Data Architect "ARC32").

If you want to know more *read the documentation*. It is installed with ARC32 (just open the Help menu) or can be read online:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=32

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/index.html

The ODBC part of your question already has answers elsewhere:

[What is the proper connection string for Advantage Database Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529924/what-is-the-proper-connection-string-for-advantage-database-server)

Comment: Thank you very much! Though I can't understand totally, but I will accept your advice to read the help firstly, maybe can help me understand your words! Thanks again!

Comment: Currently, I just focus on 4(The server itself that has an ADS service running on some socket (ip:port)), I wanna connect the server for client with IP/Port, could you please give me some guide? Thanks!

Comment: Start ARC32 -> CTRL+D (Create New Connection). You have to enter a UNC Path (\\MYSERVER\MYDATABASEDIR) or driver letter of a mapped SMB share (X:\MYDATABASEDIR) as the ConnectionPath and choose any DatabaseName you want.

Comment: While ADS connection can work without a SMB share it is easier to start *with* a SMB share to your database directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Jens